# How do you multiply the first element in a list by a number (in a list of lists) in Python?

Tags: python

I have a list of lists like this:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I would like to multiply the first element of each of the inner lists by 10. So the expected output would be this:

```
[[10,2,3],[40,5,6]]
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_list = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]

for i in my_list:
    i[0] *= 10  # multiply the first element of each of the inner lists by 10

print(my_list)
```

Output:

```
[[10, 2, 3], [40, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with large arrays, then [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) works better than python alone, for many other reasons as well.

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] # if you have your list in python

lst = np.array(lst) # simple one-liner to convert to an array

lst
Out[32]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])

lst[:,0] *= 10 # multiply first column only by 10. This removes the need
               # for python's "for" loops, which improves performance 
               # on larger arrays

lst
Out[34]: 
array([[10,  2,  3],
       [40,  5,  6]])
```